# Are pins of my Arduino fine?

Tags: pins, arduino-uno

I was making an Arduino project. It was a very safe project as I copied it from Arduino's official website. The project was about adjusting the speed of  blinking the LED on 13 pin of the Arduino.

I connected the potentiometer correctly as shown in the circuit diagram. Firstly the project was working fine, but after some time smoke started to come out from one of this pins - A0 , GND and 5V. I removed the power cable quickly. There was no damage to the board.

My questions are -

1. What is the reason behind this smoke?
2. Can these pins be used further? (I really removed power cable quickly.)

Project - https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogInput

circuit diagram below

Thanks in advance.

[image: diagram]

Comment: What value is the pot?

Comment: What was the Ohms value of the potentiometer? The arduino.cc AnalogInput tutorial doesn't specify a value, but using a very low resistance value will draw excessive supply current (Ohm's law). Smoke is a sure sign that something overheated, melting insulation or burning an IC's expoxy coating, so it's very likely that something was permanently damaged. Do you have a DVM or an oscilloscope for debugging?

Comment: I removed it from a lamp dimmer that have rating of 220V 60htz.

Comment: That’s not a resistance value. Please measure it with s multimeter or read the markings on the pot. Also, are you sure it’s an potentiometer and not a rheostat?

Comment: I've never seen smoke coming out of *pins*, and I doubt it's possible unless your pins are made of plastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. My pins are working fine I don't know how but they are working fine. And answer to second question-

I found three killer who tried to kill my arduino-

1. Arduino.cc - As they did't instructed properly.
2. light dimmer - That dimmer don't have any indication of high and low resistance. As well its potentiometer also don't have any markings.

3.Me - Its my mistake that I did't calculated its resistance and the biggest mistake that for sometime I set the value to zero ohms' And the current crossed the limit of 40mA.

Comment: If you found the answer you needed, please accept your own answer so it's marked as resolved.

Comment: it say wait 2 days to accept.

Comment: Fair enough. Whenever you get the chance then. Thanks.

Comment: "*I set the value to zero ohms' And the current crossed the limit of 40mA.*" That means that it was wired incorrectly. Your wiring diagram shows the full resistance of the pot between +5 and GND and when wired like this the current will be constant and will not change with position of the pot wiper.